# rvest::html_elements doesn't seem to respect nesting (i.e., restriction to giving results only for a nodeset)

Tags: r, rvest

If I use `rvest::html_elements` on the result of a initial call to `rvest::html_elements` it finds results outside the nodeset produced by the initial call. Is this expected behavior? It seems unlikely this would be an undiscovered bug...

```
library(rvest)
html <- minimal_html("
 <h1>This is a heading</h1>
 <p>This is a paragraph</p>
 <div><p>This is a nested paragraph</p></div>
     ")
## We get two <p> elements as expected
html %>% html_elements(xpath="//p") %>% html_text()
## [1] "This is a paragraph"        "This is a nested paragraph"

## We get only the <p> element nested within a <div>, as expected
html %>% html_elements(xpath="//div//p") %>% html_text()
## [1] "This is a nested paragraph"

## just get the <div> elements
print(html %>% html_elements(xpath="//div"))
## {xml_nodeset (1)}
## [1] <div><p id="first">This is a nested paragraph</p></div>

## Why do we get the <p> element not in a <div>?
html %>% html_elements(xpath="//div") %>% html_elements(xpath = "//p") %>% html_text() 
## [1] "This is a paragraph"        "This is a nested paragraph"
```

Comment: Yes. You are using xpath in relation to root not current node. Add `.` e.g. `html %>% html_elements(xpath="//div") %>% html_elements(xpath = "./p") %>% html_text() `  Or use css selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is expected behaviour.
You are using xpath in relation to root not current node. Add `.` to work from current node.

E.g.

```
html %>% html_elements(xpath="//div") %>% html_elements(xpath = "./p") %>% html_text()
```

Or use css selectors.